# How to differentiate between debit and credit account in SQL Server columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is some sample data:

| Transaction_ID | Amount | Credit_Account | Debit_Account | Transaction_Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TT23023F02B9 | 200 | PKR1000090662010 | 135483688 | Cash deposit |
| TT23023FX3MZ | 1658297 | PKR1000023233010 | PKR1000099993010 | Teller to Teller Transfer |
| TT23023GPNPS | 260000 | 133519319 | PKR1000073160016 | Cash Withdrawal |
| TT23023HLP3P | 342500 | 135482722 | PKR1000015443000 | Cash Withdrawal |
| TT23023JGVTC | 2046980 | PKR1000032342023 | PKR1000099992023 | Teller to Teller Transfer |
| TT23023KGGPW | 857500 | 135484137 | PKR1000050214016 | Cash Withdrawal |
| TT23023LF6J6 | 274700 | 132352909 | PKR1000031072030 | Cash Withdrawal |
| TT23023MC2FX | 263926 | PKR1000051764012 | PKR1000099994012 | Teller to Teller Transfer |
| TT23023N37H0 | 179000 | PKR1000031353007 | 132620326 | Cash deposit |
| TT23023P067S | 6400 | PKR1000014553002 | 131623003 | Cash deposit |
| TT23023PZM84 | 1561200 | 135478636 | PKR1000052572024 | Cash Withdrawal |
| FT2302348TXC | 147542 | 120673138 | 128787728 | AA Loan Payoff |

Most of the columns are self-explanatory but let explain a little.

- There are some transactions going on with unique `Transaction_ID`.
- A user can have multiple accounts, so,  `Credit_Account` and `Debit_Account` aren't unique for a user(Transaction_ID).
- `Debit_Account` is the account from which the `Amount` is transferred while `Credit_Account` is the receiving account.

I want to calculate `Total_Credit_Amount` and `Total_Debit_Amount` with respect to Accounts in both columns.

| Distinct Credt/Debit Acc | Total_Credit_Amount | Total_Debit_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | amount | amount |
| xyz | amount | amount |

I tried different iterations of `CASE` statements but all in vain.

Comment: every debit is credited to somewhere, so debit=credit: simply sum(amount)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two subqueries combined and then summarised, as follows:

```
select 
      Account
    , sum(Credit_Amount) as Credit_amount
    , sum(Debit_Amount) as Debit_amount
from (
    select 
          Credit_Account as Account
        , Amount as Credit_Amount
        , 0 as Debit_Amount
    from SomeData
    union all
    select 
          Debit_Account as Account
        , 0 as Credit_Amount
        , Amount as Debit_Amount
    from SomeData
  ) Step1
group by Account
```

Alternative not relying on union's column order:

```
select 
      Account
    , sum(case when CR_DR='CR' then Amount else 0 end) as Credit_amount
    , sum(case when CR_DR='DR' then Amount else 0 end) as Debit_amount
from (
    select 
          Credit_Account as Account
        , CR_DR='CR'
        , Amount as Amount
    from SomeData
    union all
    select 
          Debit_Account as Account
        , CR_DR='DR'
        , Amount as Amount
    from SomeData
  ) Step1
group by Account
```

Alternative using PIVOT command, based on @June7's idea (thank you):

```
select 
  Account
, Credit_Amount
, Debit_Amount
from (
    select 
          Credit_Account as Account
        , CR_DR='Credit_Amount'
        , Amount as Amount
    from SomeData
    union all
    select 
          Debit_Account as Account
        , CR_DR='Debit_Amount'
        , Amount as Amount
    from SomeData
    ) Step1
pivot (
    SUM(amount)
    FOR CR_DR IN([Credit_Amount],[Debit_Amount])
) as PT
```

Comment: An alternative would be UNION then PIVOT. I can't figure out how to get 0 to display. Likely no advantage to this approach.